# Is there a sequence that each positive real number is a partial limit for it?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

At the end of my last lecture in Calculus about Subsequences, the lecturer asked us whether there is a sequence that each positive real number is a partial limit for it, and no one could give an example, so he preferred to tell us next lecture. I'm curious about that sequence, can someone give a hint ?

(If there is no such sequence, then we need to give a complete proof that refutes this claim).

Comment: look for a dense countable subset of $\mathbb{R}$, then recall the definition of countability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A sequence that spans a dense countable subset, like $\Bbb Q$ .

Answer (score 2):

**Outline:** Imagine a flea that starts at $0$, and jumps to $1$. Then it jumps backwards in hops of $1/2$ until it reaches $-2$. Then it jumps forward in hops of $1/4$ until it reaches $4$. Then it jumps backwards in hops of $1/8$ until it reaches $-8$. Then it jumps forward in hops of $1/16$ until it reaches $16$. And so on.